# IIS not passing URL which contain diacritic symbols

Tags: url, iis, diacritics

I have a Django app installed on my IIS server. Everything works great on my local PC but links/URL on IIS app don't work if the contain diacritic symbols. If I use symbols like '%' it works fine.

Below is the code for links to attached files (both my local and server have the same code):

```
<p class="article-content mt-2 mb-1"><strong>Attachment: </strong><a href="{{post.file_close.url}}">{{post.file_close.name}}</a></p>
```

If I upload file `cars.png` everything works fine in both versions. This works no matter the extension, pdf, excel, image, etc.
Problem is, if I upload file `carsčč.png` it fails only on server side, on my PC it works great.
I get the following error on my Django/debugg:

```
Page not found (404)
“C:\inetpub\files\PyWeb\media\PN_files\2022\03\06\cars” does not exist
```

Url of the error page is:

```
http://hidden_part/media/PN_files/2022/03/06/carsčč.png
```

But when I click copy and paste it's like this:

```
http://hidden_part/media/PN_files/2022/03/06/cars%C4%8D%C4%8D.png
```

Like the link is not complete, it stopped as soon as it runs into a special character.
But, shown link still containes all the letters, it's `PN_files/2022/03/06/carsčč.png`
Tried:
I looked at regional settings, it's the same on both PCs.
Also, when I manually search for the file, the name is not currupted, it's saved localy as `carsčč.png`. So I guess it's only the link, tring to get the file.
I figured out it's because of diacritic letters. On my 'base.html' I have `meta charset="utf-8"`. Django setting `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'hr-BA'`.

I use Bootstrap 4.0 `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Server is hosted on Windows, IIS, .NET Globalization settings are set to utf-8. Do I need to add something to `Request filtering`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to set the configuration in `Request Filtering`,  IIS server will supports non-ASCII characters via this configuration，just refer to the screenshot:
[image]